# Loading a file from a python ros node

Tags: rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,  I'm writing a python node and I need to load an XML file.  I want to try to keep the XML file in my package so that way it travels with the ROS package.  However, since I typically launch nodes from my home directory, and the node is in my ROS development area, it seems I have to specify a full path in order to load the XML file.  Is there a way to ask python to give me the relative path to the current package?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10291/loading-a-file-from-a-python-ros-node/) by [andrew-unit](https://answers.ros.org/users/407/andrew-unit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 283 on 2011-06-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Best Way To Do This (tm) is probably to use a [rosparam](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosparam) to set the path to the file, and then load it that way.

If you really just want the path to the file, a proper call to roslib.rospack modulefind the directory for you.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you also could use roslaunch and the $(find) mechanism:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML

---

Originally posted by [Straszheim](https://answers.ros.org/users/44/straszheim/) with karma: 426 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1